# Group Unique Values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

First, I'm not sure that I'm using the right terminology here so feel free to correct me here. :)

I have a table where I need 2 levels of grouping(?) but with unique values only shown once. Here is my data setup;

```sql
DECLARE @FooBar TABLE(
    nickname VARCHAR(10),
    title VARCHAR(10),
    tool VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (nickname, title, tool)
);

INSERT INTO @FooBar VALUES
('panman', 'dev', 'foo'),
('panman', 'dev', 'bar'),
('panman', 'dev', 'baz'),
('panman', 'ops', 'foo'),
('panman', 'ops', 'bar'),
('panman', 'ops', 'baz'),
('manpan', 'net', 'foo'),
('manpan', 'net', 'bar'),
('manpan', 'net', 'baz'),
('manpan', 'admin', 'foo'),
('manpan', 'admin', 'bar'),
('manpan', 'admin', 'baz');

SELECT * FROM @FooBar;
```

What I would like is for each column to have the unique values grouped together. Rather than the third column listed twice, once for each `title`. So, here is my ideal table;

```
---------------------------
| nickname | title | tool |
---------------------------
| panman   | dev   | foo  |
|          | ops   | bar  |
|          |       | baz  |
---------------------------
| manpan   | net   | foo  |
|          | admin | bar  |
|          |       | baz  |
---------------------------
```

Comment: FWIW, I was able to get my ideal table by separating out the `title` into another DataSet and then using `Join(LookupSet(), vbcrlf)` to get a list of titles. However, I'd like each title to be a separate row so that I can set Tooltip to a "title description" (not shown in the example resultset), which is why I'm trying to do this with groupings or something similar...

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need a table with three levels of grouping - one for the Nickname as well as the Title and Tool.

Add a new table.

Set the Dataset name to your dataset.

Remove two columns so there's only one left.

Right-click on the three lines of the detail line in the table and go to Row Group --> Group Properties.

Add a Group On by the Nickname field. Hit OK.

Right-click again on the left of the grouped line in the table and Add Group --> Row Group Child Group. Group By Title.

Right-click again on the left of the grouped line in the table and Add Group --> Row Group Child Group. Group By Tool.

You should have a table with three columns.

The grouping will group multiple rows into one.

[MS Docs - Creating Stepped Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-stepped-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

[MS Docs - Understanding Groups in SSRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I made the same mistake. The issue is with the last column. I ran out of time looking into this but my thoughts were along the lines of transposing the data generating query results that were something like `[Column], [Value]` with values as `'nickname', 'panman'` then `'title', 'dev'` etc. This could then be pivoted in a matrix. If I get more time I'll look again - interesting problem.

Comment: I _think_ I'm following the directions correctly, but it's making the table in opposite order with the `title` duplicate for each `tool`.

Comment: @Panman - It sounds like you may have added a Parent rather than a Child. Unfortunately, Alan pointed out that the TOOL column won't work as expected. :( It's more complicated that I had thought.